# Put html file into javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm doing email templating with Handlebars. I've got a html file with my template inside. And, in **another file**, a program in javascript which will be launched by a cronjob later.

For now, I'd like to save in a variable the email template to use handlebars properly. Handlebars documentation says:

```js
var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

The thing is, I don't find a way to do it without jQuery or ajax request (everything is local). How could I proceed ?

Comment: it depends on how you code will be executed. If it is `Node JS` then it has a module `fs` which can be used for file IO

Comment: It will be node.js yes, should I get file and stringify it using fs?

Comment: Yes `fs.readFileSync('file-path.html')` will give you the desired `source` which you can pass to the `Handlebars.compile()` method

Comment: It seems to work, thanks =)